# Intermittent connection and failure to download anything more than ~100mb 22.04

Tags: wireless

https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/7tXG4wS4Db/

Lenovo Z50-75 QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter

I recently switched from windows 10 to Ubuntu a few weeks ago. The problems started immediately after install. Doesn't seem to be timed out by router ARP or anything. A quick toggle of airplane mode temporarily gets Wifi working again. I can retry downloads over and over in my browser, but have been completely barred from downloading some vscode extensions and npm packages. I've noticed a lot of CTRL-EVENT-BEACON-LOSS instances in var/log/syslog. Link quality constantly around 55/70. RX / TX packet loss. currently unable to access router options from browser.

-I tried turning off adapter power save.
-I set up network manager and disabled wpa_supplicant.
-I changed default DNS settings to google public DNS
-I've tried IPV6 both on and off
-Changed hwcrypt=1
-"dmesg -w" had instances of deauthorization error=3
-Recurring message in syslog -> [timestamp][computername] gnome-shell: "An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?"

I have no idea how many changes I've made trying to fix this. I completely lost track. I've learned almost everything I know about Linux in the past 10 hours. The only ideas I have left are to try a new kernel or follow some idea about compiling a unique driver. For now though, I've reached the extent of my problem-solving capabilities.

I would appreciate any help at all, from the very bottom of my heart too. I dont think I'll get out this rabbit hole alone

Comment: What's your WiFi MTU? Check with `ip link`. For WiFi, it should be 1492, not 1500. WiFi uses 8 more bytes of overhead than wired Ethernet. Using an MTU of 1500 on WiFi leads to "packet fragmentation" where each TCP/IP packet is sent as two packets 
 (one with 1492 data bytes, the other with 8 data bytes), with more than double the overhead.

Comment: My mtu was 1500, i changed it to 1492 with nmcli and rebooted. Pages seem to respond slightly faster but intermittency is still a problem. havent had trouble downloading since

Comment: When you rebooted, it changed back to 1500 when the connection came up.

Comment: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1472 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000. i actually lowered it more since then, and it's stuck for multiple reboots